# URL Routing - passing data outside of the URL

Tags: .net

I'm using the MVC URL rewriting functionality in a standard web forms application so I can have nice-looking URLs.

However I've reached a point in my application where I need to pass data between pages which would look both long & ugly if it was included in the URL. Up until this point I've been cutting up the URL behind the scenes, grabbing data and assigning them to the HttpContext.Items collection.

Since HttpContext.Items is per-request I clearly need to find an alternative. For various reasons I'm loathe to use either Session or Server.Transfer to do the job.

Is there any other way I can pass data around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is stateless by nature. You have two options to make it so:

- On the client: cookies
- On the server: `Session` (or something equivalent). You'll still need a cookie

So:

> Is there any other way I can pass data around?

Ehm...I guess not

Comment: This would be a bit of a flaw with nice-looking URLs then :)

I'll use a cookie - thanks.